# QuerySet object has no attribute serialize

Tags: django-rest-framework

> views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from RestAPI.mixin import JsonResponseMixIn
from .models import Update   

class SerializedListView(View):
    def get(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        qs = Update.objects.all()
        qs = qs.serialize() #error in this line
        return HttpResponse(qs , content_type="application/json")
```

serialize method is working fine with get() method but it throws an error in all() method

Exception Value:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serialize'

> models.py

```
import json
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.



class UpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        list_values = list(self.values("uesr","content","image"))
        return json.dumps(list_values)

class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think better you can define One `serializer` and get data like this:

```
class UpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Update
        fields = ("user", "content", "schedule", "image")
```

and in `view` change to this:

```
class SerializedListView(View):
    def get(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        qs = Update.objects.all()
        serializer = UpdateSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return HttpResponse(serializer.data , content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: little bit changing in the code worked for me. serialzer = UpdateSerializer(qs , many=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Update(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_update_image, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UpdateManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content or ""
```

You must have objects = UpdateManager() in model for this to work.

Comment: please fix your indentations

Comment: Sure. I didn't thought about that. Is there automatic way for that in stackoverflow? It would be helpful in future.